# Serenity Screenplay - How to add another ability to an actor later in a test?

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-platform

I'm using Serenity Screenplay + Cucumber in my test framework. I understand what an Actor is and what Abilities are and that Actor's can be setup to be allowed to perform certain actions (like calling an API).

In my Cucumber feature file, I have 2 `Given` steps, both stating that the Actor can `CallAnApi` at 2 different endpoints:

1. `Given` User can call an API at service A
2. `And` User can call an API at service B (Note that this step is performed immediately after the 1st `Given` step)

Both of these steps are written like this:
`actor.can(CallAnApi.at(<serviceBaseUri>));`

I ran the tests and found that my POST request was being sent to ServiceB, not service A, despite the fact that I explicitly define the BaseUri for service A in my POST request:

```
        File jsonPayload = new File(<FilePathToExampleJsonPayload>);
        String serviceA_Baseurl = <BaseUrlHere>;
        actor.attemptsTo(
            Post.to(<APIEndpoint>)
                    .with(request -> request
                        .baseUri(serviceA_Baseurl)
                        .body(jsonPayload))
        );
```

Now my guess is that the 2nd `Given` statement, in which Serenity is told the Actor can perform an API call to service B, overwrites the 1st `Given` statement that states that the Actor can call an API at service A. Is there a way to *ADD* abilities to an Actor that already exists without overwriting the Actor's current abilities? ***(This would be the preferred option)***

My other option is to have the abilities defined in a single `Given` step, but that would make my framework much less flexible and maintainable as I'd require a custom `Given` step for almost every test. I have around 15 services (with more coming in the future) and each test will require me to allow an Actor to access whichever services are needed for the test.

Answer (score 1):

in similar situation we decided that our actors have the ability to CallAnApi.at(""), and for the calls we use the full path, i.e. Post.to("https://serviceA.domain/path"), Get.resource("https://serviceB.domain/path"). Maybe not the most elegant solution, but so far the only one we found suitable.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that we could leave that as an empty string. We might change to this as we are using Cucumber, so the `CallAnApi.at("")` could be put into a `@BeforeAll` step or something.